# Using printf as a virtual function when it is not defined

Tags: c++, printf, virtual-functions

I am using an [LCD library from mbed](https://os.mbed.com/users/simon/code/TextLCD/), called TextLCD, and want to modify it so that it can act as the concrete class for an Interface LCD Class.

In the TextLCD driver, a `printf()` method **is declared** in the .hpp:

```
int printf(const char* format, ...);
```

However, it is **not defined** in the cpp file. Yet somehow calling `TextLCD::printf()` works.

For the interface, I want to implement:

```
// This interface class serves as a template for any LCD Driver
class LCDInterface
{
public:
 
    virtual int printf(const char* format, ...) = 0;
 
    virtual void locate(int column, int row) = 0;
 
    virtual void cls() = 0;
};
```

My assumption is that to convert the `TextLCD` driver to a concrete class, I would add the keyword `override` for the functions in the hpp accordingly:

```
int printf(const char* format, ...) override;
virtual void locate(int column, int row) override;
...
```

However, when compiling, since `printf()` itself is not defined in the driver (I think it's because it inherits from the Stream class?) I receive this error:

> Unimplemented pure virtual method 'printf' in 'TextLCD'

My two questions are:

1. How does `TextLCD::printf()` work when it is not defined (i.e. not implemented) in the cpp?
2. How can I get around this, so that the virtual function is implemented?

Comment: You need to implement the `virtual` function in the concrete class - just like your declaration promises.

Comment: But the unmodified `TextLCD` driver, does not implement the `printf` fucntion, it somehow implicitly calls back the low level stream. There is no `printf` definition in the cpp file.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. I do not see how `TextLCD` is related to `LCDInterface`. In the link you gave, `TextLCD::printf` does not `override` anything.

Comment: @WillPowell if you don't want to implement it, then remove it from the interface

Comment: I must have poorly explained, please see my new edit. My point is the unmodified TextLCD driver "printf" function is not declared/explicitly implemented. So how can I persuade the compiler that the function is implemented?

Comment: @WillPowell well where **is** it implemented? There's no "explicitly" implemented. Either it's implemented or it's not. Right now, it's not.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` is not declared in `TextLCD` (at least as long `DOXYGEN_ONLY` is not defined, which you must not define), the corresponding part in the code is:

```
#if DOXYGEN_ONLY
    /** Write a character to the LCD
     *
     * @param c The character to write to the display
     */
    int putc(int c);
 
    /** Write a formated string to the LCD
     *
     * @param format A printf-style format string, followed by the
     *               variables to use in formating the string.
     */
    int printf(const char* format, ...);
#endif
```

`DOXYGEN_ONLY` is used in case you want to have some documentation for parts of the class that otherwise would normally not be covered/generated by doxygen.

`printf` is inherited through [`Stream`](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/master/platform/include/platform/Stream.h).